# Weil-Carlitz-Uchiyama bound for Weil sum of high degree

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, characters

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, and size $q=p^n$.
Let $\chi$ be a multiplicative character of order $m$.
Then, it is well-known that the Weil sum is bounded as follows.
$$W_{\mathbb F,d}(a) = \left| \sum_{x\in \mathbb F} \chi (x^d-ax) \right| \leq (d-1)\sqrt{q}$$

I'm wondering that whether there is such generic (or for specific $d$) nontrivial bound for $d > \sqrt{q}$.
Or is this bound so tight that there is no such a nontrivial bound?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $(d−1)\sqrt q$ is an uninteresting bound when $d>\sqrt q$. This is because the sum has $q$ terms, each with absolute value one. So when $d−1\ge\sqrt{q}$, the trivial bound from the triangle inequality becomes better.

There are examples when the bound is tight.
For example, if $n$ is even, and $\chi$ is a character that is trivial on the subfield $\Bbb{E}$ of size $\sqrt q$, then $\chi(x^{\sqrt q}+x)=1$ for all $x$ because $x^{\sqrt q}+x$ belongs to $\Bbb{E}$ (as the relative trace of $x$).

I'm sure there are also examples of high degree binomials such that a non-trivial bound can be found (so a specific $q,d$ and $a$).

Comment: The Weil bound on $\sum_x\chi(f(x))$ is usually given in terms of the number of zeros of $f(x)$ in its splitting field instead of $d=\deg f$. So if $d$ is of the form $p^m+1$, then the zeros of these binomials have a high multiplicity, and we get a lower bound.

Comment: I'm quite interesting on the fact that the Weil bound is usually given in terms of the number of zeros. Could you give me any reference of it?

Comment: @wooa0923 Lidl & Niederreiter, Theorem 5.41 in my copy (2nd edition first printed in 1997).